# GWT Eclipse wont compile classes into war/WEB-INF/classes

Tags: eclipse, class, gwt, compilation

I use the GWT Version 2.5 , eclipse 3.7 and java 1.6.0_35

I am facing this problem since I manually deleted the classes in myProject/war/WEB-INF/classes . In eclipse everything looks fine, however when I compile with ant or gwt compile over eclipse it wont generate any new class in that particular folder. As consequence I receive a war file where the classes directory is empty. How can I fix it such that the classes are comming back to this folder?

Comment: Did you modify the ant script ? Did you deleted manually the classes files ? Please provide more information so the community could help you.

Comment: the ant build script is always automatically generated based on the 'google deploy button' in eclipse. And yes I deleted manually the classes.

Comment: Trying to invoke ant compile didn't solve the problem ?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the "Default Output Folder" in Project⇒Properties⇒Java Build Path points to the right place. Using built-in Ant, that's probably `myProject/war/WEB-INF/classes`.

Also, check "This Project has a WAR directory" in Project⇒Properties⇒Google⇒Web Application. For Ant, the path should be `war`.

Comment: Also check that there is to override to the output folder in the source directories above.

Comment: Worked fine for me. The directory was set to `<project>/target/classes`. The reason was that I created first a GWT project and then made a Maven Module out of it.

Comment: Not woreking for me. If I execute to the command line the command "ant gwt-compile" the .class files are not generate. This causes that if I run or "ant war" or "ant deploy" the ant returns an error saying the classes directory does not exist. If I use the deploy command inside Eclipse instead, everything is working fine. Why that?